# Python asyncio: blocking and race conditions

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to understand python's asyncio library, and am somewhat surprised by the behavior of the following example:

```
import asyncio
import time

from aiohttp import web


_lock_table = {'locked': False}


async def process(text):
    # wait while we're blocked
    while _lock_table['locked']:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    _lock_table['locked'] = True

    # hold the lock for three seconds
    # simulates "processing something"
    await asyncio.sleep(3)

    # release the lock
    _lock_table['locked'] = False


async def request_handler(request):
    text = request.query.get('text')

    start_time = time.time()
    await process(text)
    end_time = time.time()

    return web.Response(
        body='text: {}, request time: {}'.format(text, end_time - start_time),
        content_type='text/html'
    )


app = web.Application()
app.router.add_route('GET', '/', request_handler)

web.run_app(app)
```

If I start the above program and open up two requests to `http://0.0.0.0:8080` I see that both requests take around three seconds to complete. Why is this? Shouldn't the second request be blocked by the first one that acquires the lock?

Comment: The client requests you make are parallel? Can you elaborate on the method you use to create and measure them?

Comment: @user4815162342 Yes - in this case, I have a resource that must be shared. I want other processes to have to wait while that resource is locked.

I'm new to asyncio, but research seemed to indicate this approach might be simpler alternative to a multithreaded server.

Comment: But can you show how you came to the conclusion that they're not parallel? Like, share the exact code that you used to measure their performance?

Comment: @user4815162342 This is the code I've been using. I opened up two requests my browser, expected one of them to be blocked, but saw that they both pages loaded in about 3 seconds.

If this isn't the correct pattern for this kind of thing, might there be a resource you can point me to?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem you are describing. aiohttp discourages the use of global variables and suggests to use the Application object in favor of globals. But they don't seem to mention that threads are involved here. It rather seems to be a general hint for cleaner code than a necessity - so your code should be fine...

I tested your code with this example bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

pids=()
range=$(seq 1 10)
url='http://127.0.0.1:8080/?text='
for i in $range; do
    curl -o $i.txt "${url}$(date +%H%M%S)" 2>/dev/null &
    pids[$i]=$!
done

wait ${pids[$@]}

for i in $range; do
    echo "$i $(cat $i.txt)"
done
```

the output looks something like this:

```
1 text: 222331, request time: 24.153167724609375
2 text: 222331, request time: 15.077209711074829
3 text: 222331, request time: 27.17816162109375
4 text: 222331, request time: 6.0150146484375
5 text: 222331, request time: 18.09979248046875
6 text: 222331, request time: 21.1268310546875
7 text: 222331, request time: 3.004944086074829
8 text: 222331, request time: 9.03411865234375
9 text: 222331, request time: 12.050049066543579
10 text: 222331, request time: 30.205841302871704
```

You might want to make sure that the actual start time is similar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I ran the script above, things seemed to complete almost instantly. Unless I'm mistaken, shouldn't the second request that obtains the lock have to wait 6 seconds, the third request that obtains the lock 9 seconds, and so on?

Comment: It should, yes... can you add start_time to the response and post the result (`./test.sh`).

Comment: My environment for the test is python 3.6.5 with following packages:

    (venv) $ pip freeze
    aiohttp==3.3.0
    async-timeout==3.0.0
    attrs==18.1.0
    chardet==3.0.4
    idna==2.6
    idna-ssl==1.0.1
    multidict==4.3.1
    yarl==1.2.4